# A delete query in PHP need some form of validation?

Tags: php, crud

A delete query in PHP need some form of validation? besides the isset?

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM car_table WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: The best way to run a query based on user input is:
1. Validate user input and if validation fail return appropriate error.
2. If input is valid, make prepared statement to execute the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code and procedural mysqli you used, it would be something like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM car_table WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i',$id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
echo mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
```